# Using sssd for local authentication and identification against /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, sssd

This question is about RedHat Enterprise Linux 7/8/9 and Ubuntu 22.04, but it is probably pretty universal for most distros.

I have sssd working for authentication against both Active Directory and an openldap-based LDAP server, using two domains.

Users can successfully log in as user@ad.mydomain.com and authenticate against Active Directory, or log in as user@mydomain.com and authenticate against openldap. Identity information (UID, Gecos, and home directory) come from the openldap server in both cases. All relevant users exist in both systems (long story why it is set up this way, and not really relevant here).

Regardless of which of the two domains a user uses, Linux will see that login as the same user.

I just got a new requirement to add a new SSSD domain (named "local") that authenticates against the local /etc/{password,shadow}, and also obtains the identity information without any network traffic at all. /etc/password and /etc/shadow will be populated correctly (outside the scope of this question).

Is there a way to create an sssd domain that uses the local files as both authentication and identification source?

This probably isn't relevant, but here are the two existing SSSD domains.

Active Directory:

```
[domain/ad.mydomain.com]
auth_provider = krb5
id_provider = ldap
# We do not allow changing passwords
# chpass_provider = none

krb5_server = <redacted>
krb5_realm = AD.MYDOMAIN.COM

# Regardless of the auth provider, the id information always comes from
# LDAP.
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_uri = ldaps://<redacted>/
ldap_search_base = ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com
ldap_group_member = memberuid
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/cacerts/<redacted>

ldap_default_bind_dn = <redacted>
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = <redacted>
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = sshPublicKey

entry_cache_timeout = 600
ldap_network_timeout = 3
cache_credentials = True

override_homedir = /home/%u
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash

# Some performance tweaks. Without it, LDAP is painfully slow!
enumerate = false
ignore_group_members = true
```

openldap:

```
[domain/mydomain.com]
auth_provider = ldap
id_provider = ldap
# We do not allow changing passwords outside of USD_ONE
# chpass_provider = none

# Regardless of the auth provider, the id information always comes from
# LDAP.
ldap_schema = rfc2307
... Remainder is same as for Active Directory
```

What I would like to do is something along the lines of (this does not actually work):

```
[domain/local]
auth_provider = files
id_provider = files # don't use LDAP for this domain
... other parameters
```

Is there a way to get SSSD to use the local files?